# Column name mapping with data is being observed different when creating a pandas dataframe with column names given as a dictionary instead of list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm observing random results in the column name mapping to the data when the column names are specified in a dictionary instead of a list.

In the first case below, the ordering is as expected, but in the latter case the column names get incorrectly mapped to the data.

[image]

Code:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame([[23,45,67],[99,32,11]],columns={"col1","col2","col3"})
print(sample_df)
sample_df = pd.DataFrame([[23,45,67],[99,32,11]],columns={"feat1","feat2","feat3"})
print(sample_df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your column values are neither a `dictionary` nor a `list`. You have a `set` there, which are inherently unordered which is why you're seeing this result. Use square brackets to denote a `list` (which is ordered; e.g. `["col1", "col2", "col3"]`), or parentheses to denote a tuple (which is also ordered; e.g. `("col1", "col2", "col3")`).

The visual difference between a set and a dictionary is that a dictionary contains mappings via a colon `{"hello": "world"}` (this dictionary contains 1 mapping `"hello"` to `"world"`). Whereas a set does not contain mappings such as this and simply has elements separated by commas: `{"hello", "world"}` (this set contains 2 items, `"hello"` and `"world"`)

Comment: Got it, thanks! I always use a list, but tried with a set to check the difference (was confused due to its pretty rare use as compared to list and dict).

Answer (score 0):

firstly you specified `Set` in `columns` parameter ... and

> Python Set Datatype is Unordered and Unindexed [(reference)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

In Python Dict you must have `Key and Value`

try in this way -

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
```

- output

```
     col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```